# Proving there exists a hypercube inscribed in an area limit by a curve

Tags: area, covering-spaces

I am facing a problem as follows.
Given a set $A = \{X \mid X \in R^n, 0 \le f(X) \le \xi\}$, where $X=[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]^\top, \xi > 0$, $f:R^n \rightarrow R$ is a continuous function. Can we prove that there exist some numbers $a_1, a_2,\dots, a_n$ and $c_1,x_2,\dots,c_n$ such that 
\begin{align}
&|x_1 - a_1| \le c_1 \xi\\
&|x_2 - a_2| \le c_2 \xi\\
&\dots\\
&|x_n - a_n| \le c_n \xi\\
\end{align}
which is the boundary of a hypercube. 
For example, consider a simple case where $f$ is the fuction of a circle $0 \le f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 \le 1$, we can easily verify that
\begin{align}
|x - 0 | \le 1/\sqrt{2} \times 1\\
|y - 0 | \le 1/\sqrt{2} \times 1\\
\end{align}
is the square inscribed in this circles.

I don't know where to start with this problem.

Comment: What assumptions do you have on $f$?

Comment: Hi, there is no other assumption. Do we need to make some assumptions?

Comment: Look at a case where $f$ is discontinuous everywhere.

Comment: Hi, $f$ is a continuous function.

Comment: And you make the assumption (not written in your question, please update if so) that the hypercube is included in $A$?

Comment: I just want to prove that we can put a hypercube inside it, I don't need to find the exact hypercube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous and $B = \{X \in \mathbb R^n \mid 0 < f(X) < \xi \}$ not empty then $B $ is open. As all the norms in $\mathbb R^n$ are equivalent, $B$ will contain an open hypercube $H_x$ containing $x$ for all $x \in B$.